# Iterate through folder passed as argument

Tags: loops, batch-file, directory, arguments

So a bit of background: I have one of those old mp3 players that if you just drag and drop a whole folder, it then plays the songs randomly. The solution I found is to move the files one by one. But, when you have lots of folders this can be time consuming.

I am trying to make a script with Batch for Windows that moves file after file from one folder to another passed as parameters (ideally, it waits until the previous move is finished, so no moves are running in parallel. For now just added a timeout), but I am not sure if I am not using the right syntax or what I'm doing wrong (I've done a similar one in Shell, and it worked fine, but just curious).

This is the code right now:

```
@echo off
echo mvp3...

IF %%1.==. GOTO No1
IF %%2.==. GOTO No2

set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
echo before_for
for /r %%i in (%%1) do (
    echo after_for
    move %%i %%2
    timeout 1
GOTO End1

:No1
  ECHO No param 1
GOTO End1
:No2
  ECHO No param 2
GOTO End1

:End1

)
```

But if I try to run something like ./mvp3 C:\Users\folder1 C:\Users\folder2, this is the output:

```
mvp3...
before_for
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I've done a bit of duckduckgoing but couldn't find the answer, can someone illuminate me?

Thanks.

Comment: It's still `%1` and `%2`, don't double those, they're expanded as required. You cannot have and use labels within your parenthesized for-loop's `do` instruction. Windows uses back slashes for its path separators.and `(%%1)` should certainly be `(*.%1)` meaning that you should be passing just `mvp3 "C:\Users\folder1"` not `.\mvp3 C:\Users\folder1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop will allow each file to be copied completely before the next file copy will start, so no need to put in the timeout.

```
@echo off
echo mvp3...

if "%~1"=="" echo Param 1 empty & goto :eof
if "%~2"=="" echo Param 2 empty & goto :eof
for /r %%a in (%~1\*) do echo move /Y "%%a" "%~dpn2"
```

Here we simply expand `%1` and `%2` to remove double quotes if exist, then test them for being empty. then `pushd` to the source and recursively copy each `.mp3` file one after the other into the destination.

to understand variable expansion better, open `cmd` and run `for /?` read the help in the substitution of FOR variable references section.

Comment: I suggest to insert spaces around both `==` for 100% correct syntax on which `cmd.exe` does not need to automatically correct the command line.

Comment: I would suggest also to insert left to command move `if /I not "%%~dpa" == "%~f2\"` to avoid moving files in same folder if the folder passed with argument 2 is a subfolder of the folder passed with argument 1. And a different letter than `a` as loop variable would be also useful although `a` can be used here, too.

Comment: Well, `if /I not "%%~dpa" == "%~f2\"` does not work as it should if both folder arguments are UNC paths. For such a use case it would be necessary not using `pushd "%~1"` and `popd`, but use instead `for /R "%~f1" %%I in (*.mp3) do if not "%%~dpI" == "%~f2\" move /Y "%%I" "%~f2\" >nul && rd "%%~dpI" 2>nul` to get all MP3 files moved and the folders being deleted on being empty after moving a file.

Comment: Thanks sir,

That is very helpful.

However, I still get this error, so maybe I'm doing something wrong?

mvp3 C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder1 C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder2

mvp3...
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: It seems to loop through the files but something is not right. I've tried putting the folders within "", but same problem.

By the way, I want to move any file, not just *.mp3 (album covers, subfolders...), so I would use * instead. But tried it with your exact code just for testing.

Thanks.